# Cannot import framework target that pod Google/Analytics

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

In my project, I have a framework called 'Util'. I want to create a 'AnalyticHelper.swift' in that framework. So I pod 'Google/Analytics' to 'Util' target.

Here is my podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0' 
use_frameworks!

target 'GoogleAnalyticProb' do    
end

target 'Util' do   
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
end
```

Then I `import Google` in AnalyticHelper.swift

The problem is when I want to use AnalyticHelper in my main target. I need to `import Util`, and XCode says 
`Missing required module 'Google'`

Any idea how to solve this ?

Here is my example project. You can see the error in AppDelegate file.
https://github.com/ppakorn/GoogleAnalyticProblem

I've tried pod Google/Analytics to the main target to get rid of the error, I got a lot of warnings.

```
objc[37380]: Class GGLClearcutWriter is implemented in both /Users/Pakorn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueCrystal-cqptfbgzlujlfdcblsfabrkdwnrp/Build/Products/Dev-iphonesimulator/Utilities.framework/Utilities and /Users/Pakorn/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9069CB2D-4D55-44CB-BB09-04653BAE6AAD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AF714244-7C71-4252-86E2-D049EC39D765/BlueCrystal.app/BlueCrystal. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up importing the SDK directly into framework not using Pod.